# Calculating pupil magnification

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Is it possible to calculate pupil magnification, given that these lens parameters are known:

- focal length
- f-number at infinity focus
- positions of front and back principal points
- position of the entrance pupil

Of course, assuming gaussian optics and ideal lens.

Comment: Well, given that you would seem to have enough information to calculate the lens magnification but are missing the position of the exit pupil and have phrased it as a yes/no question, it looks suspiciously like a homework question where you need to answer yes or no and explain why. Is this the case?

Comment: @Mick It's not a homework question, I'm just trying to understand lenses a bit more for my job. I just tried to simplify the question as much as possible, and forgot to mention I'd actually like to calculate the pupil magnification if possible. The information I have is from a datasheet of a lens I have available.

Comment: @Mick The datasheet actually also mentions something called "exit pupil", which is a negative value in millimeters I couldn't figure out how to use to produce a meaningful result. So I wondered if the rest of the data would be enough to get an answer. Apparently not?

Comment: Well, just as lens magnification is the ratio of the relative heights (or distances) of the object and image, the pupil magnification is the ratio of the relative diameters of the entry and exit pupils.

Comment: See wikipedia for definitions of entrance and exit pupil.

Comment: @sammygerbil I know what the definitions are, I don't know if there is a relationships between entrance and exit pupils I could use to calculate the diameter of the exit one, given that I only know data about the entrance one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out by reading [a free chapter](http://iopscience.iop.org/book/978-0-7503-1242-4/chapter/bk978-0-7503-1242-4ch1) of Physics of Digital Photography by Andy Rowlands.

Besides focal length, knowing either entry or exit pupil position in relation to its principal point is enough to calculate the pupil magnification. The expressions involved are:

$s_{ep} = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{m_p} \right) f$

$s'_{xp} = \left( 1 - m_p \right) f$

In the equations above:

- $s_{ep}$ is distance of the entry pupil from the front principal point (positive direction is towards the object-side)
- $s'_{xp}$ is the distance of the exit pupil from back principal point (positive direction is towards the image-side)
- $m_p$ is pupil magnification
- $f$ is the focal length